# Как отрисовать в цикле for кирпичную стену на python

Tags: python, графика, simple-draw

Есть библиотека `simple_draw` для отрисовки простых графических примитивов.
Не могу понять как отрисовать цикл вертикальных линий, точнее у меня получается в каждом ряду по одной линии со сдвигом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
width = 100
height = 50
x = 0
y = 0
x_1 = 100
y_1 = 50
rows = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

x0 = 0
y0 = 0
x1 = 600
y1 = 0
x_v_0 = 0
y_v_0 = 0
x_v_1 = 0
y_v_1 = 50

for row in rows:
    y1 += 50
    start_point = sd.get_point(0, y1)
    end_point = sd.get_point(600, y1)

    sd.line(start_point=start_point, end_point=end_point, color=sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=6)


    for row_v in range(6):
        x_v_0 += width
        y_v_0 += height
        x_v_1 += width
        y_v_1 += height
        start_point1 = sd.get_point(x_v_0, y_v_0)
        end_point1 = sd.get_point(x_v_1, y_v_1)
        sd.line(start_point=start_point1, end_point=end_point1, color=sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил задачу таким способом - меньше переменных:

```
width = 100
height = 50
y = 0
y1 = height
for i in range(12):
    start_point = sd.get_point(0, y)
    end_point = sd.get_point(600, y)
    sd.line(start_point, end_point, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=3)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        x1 = 0
        x2 = 0
        for _ in range(7):
            start_point = sd.get_point(x1, y)
            end_point = sd.get_point(x2, y + y1)
            sd.line(start_point, end_point, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=3)
            x1 += width
            x2 += width
    else:
        x1 = width/2
        x2 = width/2
        for _ in range(6):
            start_point = sd.get_point(x1, y)
            end_point = sd.get_point(x2, y + y1)
            sd.line(start_point, end_point, sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=3)
            x1 += width
            x2 += width
    y += height
```

Answer (score 10):

В цикле

```
for row_v in range(6):
```

Вы одновременно увеличиваете координату `x` и координату `y`

```
x_v_0 += width
y_v_0 += height
x_v_1 += width
y_v_1 += height
```

А нужно рассматривать такую стену, как двумерный массив, т.е. сначала мы проходим по первой строке и отрисовываем вертикальные линии, при этом координата `y` не изменяется, а изменяется только координата `x`. При переходе к следующей строке `y` увеличивается, а `x` обнуляется. При этом, чтобы получилась действительно похожая кирпичная стена, нужно через строку добавлять сдвиг, равный половине длины кирпича.

```
for row in rows:
    y1 += 50
    start_point = sd.get_point(0, y1)
    end_point = sd.get_point(600, y1)

    sd.line(start_point=start_point, end_point=end_point, color=sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=6)
    # Четная строка
    if row % 2 == 0:
        x_v_0 = 0
        x_v_1 = 0  
        for row_v in range(7):
            start_point1 = sd.get_point(x_v_0, y_v_0)
            end_point1 = sd.get_point(x_v_1, y_v_1)
            sd.line(start_point=start_point1, end_point=end_point1, color=sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=6)
            x_v_0 += width    
            x_v_1 += width
    # Нечётная строка
    else:
        # Сдвиг
        x_v_0 = width / 2
        x_v_1 = width / 2 
        for row_v in range(6):
            start_point1 = sd.get_point(x_v_0, y_v_0)
            end_point1 = sd.get_point(x_v_1, y_v_1)
            sd.line(start_point=start_point1, end_point=end_point1, color=sd.COLOR_ORANGE, width=6)
            x_v_0 += width    
            x_v_1 += width

    # Закончили рисовать одну строку, увеличиваем координаты `y`            
    y_v_0 += height    
    y_v_1 += height
```

[image: Стена]

Comment: Круто однако)))

Comment: @Flippy Если ответ полезный, то автору всегда приятно, когда его ответ отмечают как полезный. А если ответ еще и решил задачу, то нужно отмечать его как принятый.

Comment: Теперь понял ))

Answer (score 4):

можно еще короче через рисование прямоугольника

```
#размеры кирпича он же шаг отступа
step_x = 100
step_y = 41

wall_length = 600

#функция рисует прямоугольники в ряд
def print_brick_line(start_x, start_y, wall_length, step_x, step_y):
    for x in range(start_x, wall_length, step_x):
        point1 = sd.get_point(x, start_y)
        point2 = sd.get_point(x + step_x, start_y + step_y)
        sd.rectangle(left_bottom=point1, right_top=point2, color=sd.COLOR_RED, width=2)

for y in range(1, wall_length, step_y):

    # Четное
    if y % 2 == 0:
        print_brick_line(start_x=(step_x-step_x), start_y=y, wall_length=wall_length, step_x=step_x, step_y=step_y)

    # Нечётное
    else:
        print_brick_line(start_x=((step_x//2)-step_x), start_y=y, wall_length=wall_length, step_x=step_x, step_y=step_y)
```

Answer (score 1):

*В задании говорится использовать вложенные циклы **for:***

```
    import simple_draw as sd
    
    # Нарисовать стену из кирпичей. Размер кирпича - 100х50
    # Использовать вложенные циклы for
```

**Вводим исходные данные:**

*Придаём немного универсальности. Размеры стены, кирпича и шва могут быть любыми*

```
    wall_width = 1920  # int(input('Введите ширину стены: '))
    wall_height = 1080  # int(input('Введите высоту стены: '))
    brick_width = 100  # int(input('Введите ширину кирпича: '))
    brick_height = 50  # int(input('Введите высоту кирпича: '))
    seam = 4  # int(input('Введите толщину шва: '))
```

[image: например так]

**Предварительные расчёты:**

*Получаем количество рядов. Задаём переменную **quantity_rows**, и в ней делим высоту стены на высоту кирпича.
Это нам понадобится для отрисовки рядов кладки кирпичей в основном цикле **for**  (что бы он понимал сколько раз пройтись по вложенным циклам повторяя отрисовку ряда)*

```
quantity_rows = wall_height // brick_height
```

*Делим кирпич пополам. Переменная **half_brick** понадобится во втором вложенном цикле **for**, для сдвига вертикальных линий кладки.*

```
    half_brick = brick_width // 2
```

*Назначаем переменные координат и задаём им первоначальные значения, **ВАЖНО** некоторые из них с отрицательным значением, для правильного вхождения в цикл (входим с отрицательным а далее уже внутри только увеличиваем перед и после отрисовки линий что бы, так сказать, перескакивать через ряд)*

```
    b_h = -brick_height  # Variable brick height
    x_1 = -brick_height  # Variables of a row of bricks
    y_1 = 0              #
    x_2 = 0              # Variables of a row of bricks with an offset
    y_2 = brick_height   #
```

*Передаём импортируемой функции разрешение экрана (размер стены) и цвет фона (кирпичей)*

```
    sd.resolution = (wall_width, wall_height)
    sd.background_color = sd.COLOR_DARK_ORANGE
```

*Первый цикл (головной). Он будет повторять содержимое столько раз, сколько мы заранее высчитали рядов **quantity_rows***

*До отрисовки первой горизонтальной лини к переменной **b_h** прибавляем высоту кирпича, что бы убрать её отрицательное значение, и когда цикл вернётся к этой строке вновь за вторым, третьим и т.д. рядами, она уже будет поднимать линию на ряд выше.*

*p.s Ладно. Похоже давление поднялось. Надеюсь смог донести хотя бы суть каши внизу. Не судите строго, сам только учусь.*

*p.p.s Во вложенных циклах в аргументах функции range в **wall_width** прибавил **+1**, для того что бы в конце ряда дорисовывалась вертикальная линия*

```
    for horizontal_lines in range(quantity_rows):
        b_h += brick_height
        sd.line(start_point=sd.get_point(0, b_h),
                end_point=sd.get_point(wall_width, b_h),
                color=sd.COLOR_BLACK,
                width=seam)
    
        x_1 += brick_height
        y_1 += brick_height
    
        for vertical_lines in range(0, wall_width+1, brick_width):
            sd.line(start_point=sd.get_point(vertical_lines, x_1),
                    end_point=sd.get_point(vertical_lines, y_1),
                    color=sd.COLOR_BLACK,
                    width=seam)
    
        x_1 += brick_height
        y_1 += brick_height
        b_h += brick_height
    
        sd.line(start_point=sd.get_point(0, b_h),
                end_point=sd.get_point(wall_width, b_h),
                color=sd.COLOR_BLACK,
                width=seam)
    
        x_2 += brick_height
        y_2 += brick_height
    
        for vertical_lines_offset in range(half_brick, wall_width+1, brick_width):
            sd.line(start_point=sd.get_point(vertical_lines_offset, x_2),
                    end_point=sd.get_point(vertical_lines_offset, y_2),
                    color=sd.COLOR_BLACK,
                    width=seam)
    
        x_2 += brick_height
        y_2 += brick_height
    
    sd.pause()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Старайтесь чуть подробнее комментировать Ваше решение словами. Замечание про влоэенные циклы - уже хорошо, но не факт, что пользователь который до этого не смог сам реализовать данную задачу сможет понять данное решение. Чирканите несколько строк, которые хотя бы поверхностно объясняют идею вашего решения, основные проблемы автора вопроса, какими приемами вы пользовались во время решения, etc.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, исправил )

Comment: Отлично, плюсик вам за это)

Answer (score 0):

```py
for y in range(0, 1000, 50):
    x = int(y / 50) % 2 * 50
    for x in range(x, 1500, 100):
        point_1 = sd.get_point(x, y)
        point_2 = sd.get_point(x + 100, y + 50)
        sd.rectangle(point_1, point_2, width=2)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Решил используя функцию sd.rectangle которая рисует прямоугольники. Несомненно решение @Андрей Колесников, элегантнее, на мой взгляд, с определением чётных и не чётных строк в выражение 'x'.

Моё решение как бы распаковывает решение [Андрея Колесникова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/424981/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

```
    import simple_draw as sd

sd.resolution = 600, 600

# цикл отрисовывает шесть строчек, в каждой по шесть кирпичей
# в начале каждой строки х = 0 , y = 0 и увеличивается на 100 в следущей строчке
for y in range(0, 600, 100):
    x = 0
    # цикл рисут шесть кирпичей в строчке
    for x in range(x, 600, 100):
        start_poin = sd.get_point(x, y)
        end_point = sd.get_point(x + 100, y + 50)
        sd.rectangle(start_poin, end_point, width=1)
# цикл отрисовывает следующие шесть строчек, в каждой по шесть кирпичей
# в начале каждой строки х = -50, а у начинается с 50 и увеличивается на 100
for y in range(50, 600, 100):
    x = -50
    # цикл рисует кирпичи в строке
    for x in range(x, 600, 100):
        start_poin = sd.get_point(x, y)
        end_point = sd.get_point(x + 100, y + 50)
        sd.rectangle(start_poin, end_point, width=1)

sd.pause()
```

Результат такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
offset = 0
for _y in range(0, 1001, 50):
    offset += 1
    if offset % 2:
        for _x in range(0, 1001, 100):
            sd.rectangle(sd.get_point(_x, _y), sd.get_point(_x+100, _y+50), width=1)
    else:
        for _x in range(-50, 1001, 100):
            sd.rectangle(sd.get_point(_x, _y), sd.get_point(_x+100, _y+50), width=1)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] 2. ваш [другой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1495311/178576) ничем не отличается от данного. возникает подозрение, что как минимум один из ответов не является ответом на тот вопрос, под которым он размещён.